# How to correctly set up :make for building Vim?

Tags: quickfix, linux, errorformat, make

My question could fairly be a duplicate of [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14196/need-help-with-vim-errorformat-to-parse-multi-line-make-gcc-output), but I hope I'm making it critically different by asking about `:make`ing **Vim itself** and having a meaningful quickfix window. (In reality, my use case is that of building my codebase, but if I can't get `:make` doing the right thing for Vim, what's the point of wandering?)

---

I would have expected that running `:make` in Vim's repo would result in an empty quickfix window (no errors, as no errors, is what I get if I compile in the terminal via `make`).

But instead, it looks like the qf is populated with several lines of the output, even if none of them represents an error. In the screencast below, indeed, I use `:cnext` to move from "error" 1 of 16 (at time 00:10) to 16 of 16 (at time 00:28) and they all look like a piece of the output, e.g.

```
(11 of 16): make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
```

So the first part of the question is why does `:make` populate the qf window with non-error-nor-warning items?

---

When there is indeed a compilation error (e.g. in the screencast below, at time 00:40, I've removed a `{` of the `AutoPatCmd_S` struct, thus making the file erroneous, and run `:make` again, at time 00:44), `:cnext` eventually brings me in an object file (at time 1:15 onward), which I also suspect is not particularly useful.

What settings do I need to make Vim do the right thing as far as the qf for errors of `:make` is concerned?

[image: asciicast]

Comment: I'm on HEAD and I get no error. Besides, if `:help 'makeprg'` is set to `make`, then there is no intrinsic difference between being called via `:make`, `:!make`, or `$ make`. There can be some extrinsic differences like environment variables or aliases but that's all. It's just `make`.

Comment: @romainl, sorry for the confusion, but what I meant is that I edited the file to cause an error. As you can see in the screencast.

Comment: I can't see anything in the screencast. It is too fast and lacks all kinds of context cues.

Comment: @romainl, I've tried to improve the question.

Comment: That is one of the cases that lead me to create vim-shout recently: https://asciinema.org/a/Mw5VpaDHJ0Ifk71bAWD7Er5Ak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:make` executes `:help 'makeprg'`, grabs its output, parses it with `:help 'errorformat'`, and then populates the quickfix list with "valid" errors, eg stuff that passed the parsing phase.

One problem, here, is that `make` is run from the root of the project, which means that it is the root `Makefile` that is used, which means that it will output lots of ultimately useless "Entering/Leaving directory XXX" messages that will pollute your quickfix list, as well as non-existing paths and so on.

With `src` as working directory, `make` uses `src/Makefile`, which results in a usable quickfix list/window.

[image: make]

Comment: I don't get an exactly identical qf. I guess it is a GCC vs Clang difference?

Comment: That's a possibility, yes.